# Setting nested object to null if

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a new object in Javascript, based off the contents of an existing object.

*Variation 1*

```
const existing_obj = {
  invoice: {
    pdf: 'string',
    payment: null
  }
}
```

*Variation 2*

```
const existing_obj = {
  invoice: {
    pdf: 'string',
    payment: {
      id: 'string',
      status: 'string'
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to do is the say:

*Result*

```
const existing_obj = {
  invoice: {
    pdf: 'string',
    payment: 'IF VARIATION 1, SET TO NULL. IF VARIATION 2, SET CERTAIN FIELDS FROM VARIATION 1 
  }
}
```

I know I could write a ternary statement to set the whole object, but I just want to select a certain field from the object.  for example only the status

Comment: Can't you do -
const existing_obj = {
  invoice: {
    pdf: 'string',
    payment: {
      status: 'string'
    }
  } | null
}